# What does \d in Javascript regex do?

Tags: javascript, regex

What does `\d` do in this example?

```
/Chapter (\d+)\.\d*/
```

Comment: Different things depending on where you put it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In what context?

In a regular expression, it matches a digit (0-9).

**Edit**, according to your comment:

It matches any string starting with Chapter, followed by digits, then a dot, then a number of digits. Like `Chapter 1.0` and `Chapter 12.01`.

Comment: `/Chapter (\d+)\.\d*/` <- how is it used?

Comment: It matches any string starting with Chapter, followed by digits, then a dot, then a number of digits. Like `Chapter 1.0` and `Chapter 12.01`. You should update your original question with that one.

Comment: That is a regular expression. It helps matching patterns. Google has plenty of information about it.

Comment: It's for grouping. You can access a group by \1 for the first group, \2 for the second and so on. More info here http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=regexp+grouping&parent=js+regexp

Comment: It would also match "Chapter 1.", without anything after the dot. Anyway, it looks like the purpose is actually to detect the main chapter number, right before the dot, which is what the parens do.

Answer (score 4):

In a regex it means digits 0-9

`\d`    Digits 0 through 9  `/H\d/` matches "H3"

Answer (score 2):

If it is in a regular expression (`match` or `replace` or `split`) or a `/`...`/` string then it probably means match any digit 0-9. Please provide the code you see it in so we can be sure.

Comment: `/Chapter (\d+)\.\d*/` <- how is it used?

Comment: That is a regular expression to match the word `Chapter` followed by space, then one or more digits `(\d+)` (these first digits are captured to `$1` I don't know if you are using `$1` or ignoring it). After that it matches a dot `\.`, then it is allowed but not required to have digits after the dot `\d*`